# What type of damage does Technician deal?

Tags: hawken

In Hawken, optimization points and internals are separated by bullet damage and explosive damage. The technician fires energy pellets(bullet like) with a very small AOE (explosive like) and its beam is just that.. a beam, neither bullet nor explosive.

What damage type should I optimize to get the most damage/heal from Technician?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when you posted this (probably last year ...god I'm late) but I'll answer you anyways.

The tech is not really made for damage.
He is a support mech.

The helix torch is actually a sustain type.

As u said there are 2 types, sustain and burst

Sustain is like constant steady damage while burst is a big chunk of dammage (just like explosions).

The tech is made for healing and supporting but not that much for damage.

His redox has a little bit of aoe like you said but does little damage. 
The upside of this weapon is that it has a debuff effect. It increases the enemy mech's damage taken for a moment and stacks up till 3 I think.

The best way to use it I think is by just sticky with an ally (preferably a c class also called a heavy class), heal them while they are in battle while also giving supporting fire.

There are also at her weapons you can buy for the tech but they are more for offense... (Why play support class to go offense.... Unless your team isn't going on the offense...)

So overall it all depends on your play style.